# Win32 WM_SIZE message gives wrong dimensions

Tags: c, winapi

I am working on some OpenGL interface stuff and noticed that when I startup my application the WM_SIZE message gets send with width=1260 and height=677, even though I created the window with width=1280 and height=720.

Here is how I create the window:

```
MainWindow.handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, windowClass.lpszClassName,
        "Some window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 
        NULL, NULL, instance, NULL);
```

This is how I handle WM_SIZE:

```
case WM_SIZE: {
    Camera.width = LOWORD(lParam);
    Camera.height = HIWORD(lParam);
    MainWindow.width = LOWORD(lParam);
    MainWindow.height = HIWORD(lParam);
    glViewport(0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
} break;
```

I suspect that those values (1260, 677) are wrong and not the actual window dimensions, since my interface 'hitboxes' are slightly off. If I resize the window manually, no matter how much, the correct WM_SIZE is send and the hitboxes are fine.

My question is why is this first WM_SIZE even send and why are those values slightly off? Can I maybe send an extra manual WM_SIZE to combat the initial WM_SIZE?

Comment: They are not off. The `WM_SIZE` gives you the size of the client area, not the window.

Comment: So it excludes the bar at the top of the window?

Comment: Yes. (plus 10 characters)

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) lots of times. Please do some research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) documentation:

> *lParam*
>
> The low-order word of lParam specifies the new width of the **client area**.
>
> The high-order word of lParam specifies the new height of the **client area**.

You are expecting the values to give you the dimensions of the *entire window*, but it gives you the dimensions of only the *client area*.

[image]

Use [`GetWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) to get the position and dimensions of the entire window.

Otherwise, if you want the *client area* to be a particular size, use [`AdjustWindowRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrect) or [`AdjustWindowRectEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-adjustwindowrectex) to calculate the necessary *window* size before calling `CreateWindowEx()`, eg:

```
RECT r;
r.left = 0;
r.top = 0;
r.right = 1280;
r.bottom = 720;
AdjustWindowRectEx(&r, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE, WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

MainWindow.handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, windowClass.lpszClassName,
        "Some window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, r.right-r.left, r.bottom-r.top, 
        NULL, NULL, instance, NULL);
```